# Instantiate a method template of a class template

Tags: templates, c++11, instantiation

How can I explicitely instantiate method `f` of the following snippet?

```
template <int x> class A
{
public:
   template <typename T> inline void f(T y) { y = x; }
};
```

Comment: not sure if you would like something to happen in your function, but maybe you should pass a reference `f(T & y) = { y = x; }`

Comment: Well, that was some senseless example that is doing nothing. Anyway thanks for your trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
template void A<0>::f<int>(int);
```

Obviously substitute `0` and `int` for what you want to instantiate with.

Comment: Is writing "template <>" instead of "template" an allowed syntax here?

Comment: @Silicomancer No, `template<>` is for explicit specialization, not explicit instantiation.

Comment: Can we eliminate explicit `<int>` here?

Comment: @alexolut Huh, apparently you can.